# In pyqt6, why QSlider cannot see handler after using qss?

Tags: python, handle, qtstylesheets, pyqt6, qslider

```py
class VideoProgressSlider(QSlider):
    def __init__(self, orientation: Qt.Orientation = Qt.Orientation.Horizontal):
        super().__init__(orientation)
        self.__initUI()

    def __initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)
        self.setStyleSheet(f'''
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {{ 
                height: 12px; 
                left: 0px; 
                right: 0px; 
                border:0px;    
                border-radius:6px;
                background:rgba(0,0,0,50);
             }} 
             QSlider::handle:horizontal{{ 
                width: 8px;
                height: 16px;
                margin-top: -8px; 
                margin-left: 1px; 
                margin-bottom: -8px; 
                margin-right: 1px;
                # core code which results in the question
                border-image: {os.path.join('../../Resources', "circle.png")};
                border: 8px solid;
            }} 
            QSlider::sub-page:horizontal{{
                border:0px;    
                border-radius:6px;
                background:qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #12b9ff, stop: 1.0 #015eea);
            }}
        ''')
        pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        # Make sure the handle will go to the position where I clicked.
        # Omitted.
        pass
```

As I provide above, there is a new `QSlider` which was modified **the style sheet** and added some functions.
And this is the effect Pic.

[image: Effect]

I have no idea how to fix it.
Hoping for solutions.

I try to use
`border-image: {os.path.join('../../Resources', "circle.png")};`,
`border-image: url({os.path.join('../../Resources', "circle.png")});`,
`border-image: url(:/{os.path.join('../../Resources', "circle.png")});`
and even the full path.
But none of them is useful.
The handle picture which is named `circle.png` is 16px(**I even tried 5px**), and the path **was verified** by using the terminal to access.

---

Additional Information
This is part of the tree structure of the project.

```
D:\...\CODE\GUI
│  ...
│
├─Dev
│  ├─Login
│  │    ...
│  │
│  ├─Modules
│  │    ...
│  │
│  ├─MyWidgets
│  │    MyMediaPlayWidget.py
│  │    VideoProgressSlider.py
│  │    ...
│  │
│  └─Utils
│       ...
│ 
└─Resources
      circle.png
      ...
```

Comment: Typo: you must use quotes for paths, and they should always be as `url()`. `border-image: url("{os.path.join('../../Resources', "circle.png")}")`. Note that you should not use hardcoded relative paths, always use references to the `__file__` to create the final path.

Comment: @musicamante thank you so much for pointing this out. but I tried to wrap the path with `url("")` and it seems like `border-image: url("D:\...\Code\GUI\Resources\circle.png");`. I cannot see the handle of the slide. I updated the question and posted part of the project structure.

Comment: Ensure that you're properly constructing the correct path, and provide a valid reproducible example of how you do it, because if you do use the `url("...")` syntax and it doesn't work, either the path is invalid, or the image isn't. Remember what said above: you should not use hardcoded relative paths like `../..`, as they become relative to the working dir.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution just use :
"QSlider::handle {image: url('path');}"
and not background-image or border-image.
Here is an example i made (i had to reformat the absolute path to get it right, but i dont succeed to change the size of the image if you can help me) :

```
self.script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path_to_image = os.path.join(self.script_dir, "../../ressources/Icon/potar1.png")
abspath1 = os.path.abspath(path_to_image)
abspath1 = abspath1.replace("\\", "/")
print("chemin potar:" ,abspath1)
    
self.myslider.setStyleSheet(f"QSlider::handle {{height:227px;width:109px;image: url({abspath1});}}"
        "QSlider::add-page{}"
        "QSlider::sub-page {background-color: green;}")
```